# Angular 2 with SharePoint provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, 403, angular2

I have one requirement to create **SharePoint Provider hosted app** with **Angular 2**. I have beginner level knowledge about SharePoint app with Angular2.

I have created one **SharePoint Provider hosted app** with **MVC web application**. SharePoint app is installed in Office 365 and MVC web application is hosted in local IIS. Basic SharePoint app is working fine.

I have also created all files required for Angular 2 in web application like: Package.json, tsconfig.json, typings.json, etc. Angular 2 code is working fine in SharePoint app.

My **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "aspnet",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typings": "0.8.1" 
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.9"
  }
}
```

My code for accessing data is:

```
makeRequest(
        reqURL: "https://<server-name>sharepoint.com/sites/ProviderApp/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('TestAngular')/Items?$select=Title,Number",
        search: URLSearchParams = null,
        body: string = null,
        method: RequestMethod = RequestMethod.Post,
        headers: Headers = new Headers({ accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json; odata=verbose' })
    ) {
        let reqOptions = new RequestOptions({
            url: reqURL,
            method: method,
            headers: headers,
            body: body,
            search: search
        });
        let req = new Request(reqOptions)
        return this._http.request(req).map((res) => { return res.json().d });
    }
```

### **My Problem is:**

When I am trying to access the host web SharePoint list data from app using **HTTP directive**, it gives **403 Forbidden** error. I am not able to access the SharePoint data into the app. Other than Angular 2 code is working fine in the app.

Error suggests that there may be some issue for passing authorisation to the SharePoint for accessing the data. But I am unable to resolve this issue.

It's giving below error in browser console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
> (FORBIDDEN)
>
> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
> access this resource.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Checked permissions in appmanifest.xml ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have given permissions for Site Collection and list as "Full Control" but its giving same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution after lots of googling and brain-stroming. I am not able to solve the **REST API - 403 error** issue but I got work around for this.

I have created Web APIs in MVC project for all SharePoint operations that I wanted to do using REST API.

Create Filter for getting SharePoint context in Web API for SharePoint operations.

## 3 easy Steps:

### 1.

Change **WebApiConfig.cs** to enable Session State in Web API

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.WebHost;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace MyWebApi
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            ).RouteHandler = new SessionRouteHandler();
        }

        public class SessionRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
        {
            IHttpHandler IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
            {
                return new SessionControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
            }
        }
        public class SessionControllerHandler : HttpControllerHandler, IRequiresSessionState
        {
            public SessionControllerHandler(RouteData routeData)
                : base(routeData)
            { }
        }
    }
}
```

### 2.

Create a new filter called **SharePointContextWebAPIFilterAttribute.cs** behind Filters folder.

**SharePointContextFilterAttribute.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using ActionFilterAttribute = System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute;

namespace MyWebApi
{
    public class SharePointContextWebAPIFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
            }

            Uri redirectUrl;
            switch (SharePointContextProvider.CheckRedirectionStatus(HttpContext.Current, out redirectUrl))
            {
                case RedirectionStatus.Ok:
                    return;
                case RedirectionStatus.ShouldRedirect:
                    var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
                    response.Headers.Add("Location", redirectUrl.AbsoluteUri);
                    actionContext.Response = response;
                    break;
                case RedirectionStatus.CanNotRedirect:
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, "Context couldn't be created: access denied");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes** in the above code:

- System.Web.Http.Controllers.**HttpActionContext** doesn't have **HttpContext** object associated, so we will use **HttpContext.Current** instead inside OnActionExecuting when called CheckRedirectionStatus method from SharePointContextProvider class.
- System.Web.Http.Controllers.**HttpActionContext** doesn't have Result property, we will use Response property to redirect and create Error response in the code.

### 3.

Use **SharePointContextWebAPIFilter** instead SharePointContextFilter in our **Web API actions**:

```
using Microsoft.Azure;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MyWebApi
{
  public class MyCustomController : ApiController
  {
    [SharePointContextWebAPIFilter]
    public string Get(string name, string number)
    {
        List TestAngular = null;

        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext.Current);

        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                TestAngular = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestAngular");
                clientContext.Load(TestAngular);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem oListItem = TestAngular.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                oListItem["Title"] = name;
                oListItem["Number"] = number;

                oListItem.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                return "Data saved!";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error occurred!";
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### How to test this approach is working

1. If we go directly to our REST Service:

`http://<localhost>/api/mycustom?name=TestAngular&number=1`

We will receive this error:

[image]

2. If we go to our SharePoint Provider-hosted app and we click on our App Launcher we will be redirected to login page and after that to an url like that:

`http://<localhost>/home/index/?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant%2Esharepoint%2Ecom&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=16%2E0%2E5625%2E1208&SPAppWebUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant-appguid%2Esharepoint%2Ecom&SPHasRedirectedToSharePoint=1`

This isn’t our Web API, but is our gateway to login into Provider-hosted app. Once logged in, we can change the url “home/index” by our REST call, for example:

`http://<localhost>/api/mycustom?name=TestAngular&number=1&SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant%2Esharepoint%2Ecom&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=16%2E0%2E5625%2E1208&SPAppWebUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant-appguid%2Esharepoint%2Ecom&SPHasRedirectedToSharePoint=1`

That should give you the information requested in the browser.

**Reference:**

- https://blog.josequinto.com/2016/09/05/how-to-provide-sharepointcontext-to-a-web-api-action-apicontroller-in-a-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app/

---

## Use in Angular2

After creating Web API and Filter in the MVC web application, you can access that API in Angular2 using **HTTP directive** as per below code chunk:

```
let listUrl = `https://localhost/api/mycustom?name=${form.name}&number=${form.number}&SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant%2Esharepoint%2Ecom&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=16%2E0%2E6406%2E1200&SPAppWebUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant-appguid%2Esharepoint%2Ecom`;

        let reqOptions = new RequestOptions({
            url: listUrl,
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            headers: new Headers({ accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json; odata=verbose' }),
            body: null
        });
        let req = new Request(reqOptions)
        this._http.request(req).map((res) => {
            return res.json()
        }).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

**Reference:**
 - [Use Angular 2 with Asp.Net](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/07/05/how-to-use-angular2-with-aspnet-4-5-aspnetmvc-5/)

Comment: This is very good solution. It helps me. Good job.

Comment: How did you get angular 2 working with provider hosted (not SharePoint hosted)? Whenever I click on the add in though SharePoint I get Method Not Allowed until I refresh the page.

Comment: You can attach Angular2 code with MVC web application with simple steps as shown here: https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/07/05/how-to-use-angular2-with-aspnet-4-5-aspnetmvc-5/